# LibreOffice Java - Cannot Cast uno.Any to XPropertySet

Tags: java, libreoffice

I am attempting to use Java to interact with the LibreOffice API. Presently, I am working on creating a helper class for actions such as retrieving objects, inserting text, and the like. However, I am having trouble with applying validation to a spreadsheet document. My function is as follows:

```
 public static void applyValidation(int x1, int y1,  int x2, int y2, XSpreadsheet sheet, ValidationType type) throws UnknownPropertyException, WrappedTargetException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalArgumentException, PropertyVetoException {
        XCellRange range = sheet.getCellRangeByPosition(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        XPropertySet propSet = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, range);

        XPropertySet validProp =(XPropertySet) propSet.getPropertyValue("Validation");
        validProp.setPropertyValue("ShowErrorMessage", new Boolean(true));
        validProp.setPropertyValue("ErrorMessage", "Please enter a valid time");
        validProp.setPropertyValue("ErrorAlertStyle", ValidationAlertStyle.INFO);



         propSet.setPropertyValue("Validation", validProp);

  }
```

It is modeled after the example provided in the [OpenOffice Developer's Guide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Other_Table_Operations).

I am attempting to call the method from a test class:

```
@Test
public void test() {
try {
XComponentLoader loader = LibreBootstrapper.getLoader();
    assertTrue( (loader instanceof XComponentLoader));
    XSpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetHelper.getSpreadsheetDoc(loader);
    assertTrue( (doc instanceof XSpreadsheetDocument));
    XSpreadsheet sheet = SpreadsheetHelper.getSheetByIndex(SpreadsheetHelper.getSheets(doc), 0);
    SpreadsheetHelper.insertIntoCell(0, 0, sheet, 400);
    SpreadsheetHelper.insertIntoCell(1, 0, sheet, 300);
    SpreadsheetHelper.insertFormula(2, 0, sheet, "=SUM(A1:B1)");
    SpreadsheetHelper.insertIntoCell(2, 2, sheet, "Hello World!");
    SpreadsheetHelper.setProperty(0, 0, 8, 10, sheet, "CellStyle", "Heading 1");
    int formatCode = SpreadsheetHelper.getFormatCode(doc, NumberFormat.TIME);   
    SpreadsheetHelper.setProperty(0, 0, 8, 10, sheet, "NumberFormat", formatCode);
    SpreadsheetHelper.applyValidation(0, 0, 8, 10, sheet,  ValidationType.TIME);

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.star.uno.Any cannot be cast to com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet
```

which has the following stack

```
    at edu.cmu.office.SpreadsheetHelper.applyValidation(SpreadsheetHelper.java:125)
    at HelperTests.test(HelperTests.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

I even tried essentially copying and pasting the code from the example (linked to above) but still received the same error.

I am not too familiar with the LibreOffice API; any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

The line actually throwing the error is as follows:

```
            XPropertySet validProp =(XPropertySet) propSet.getPropertyValue("Validation");
```

Even if directly copy and paste from the example, I receive the same error:

```
      public static void applyValidation(int x1, int y1,  int x2, int y2, XSpreadsheet sheet, ValidationType type) throws UnknownPropertyException, WrappedTargetException, IndexOutOfBoundsException, IllegalArgumentException, PropertyVetoException {

//          XCellRange range = sheet.getCellRangeByPosition(x1, y1, x2, y2);
//          XPropertySet propSet = (XPropertySet)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, range);
//
//          XPropertySet validProp =(XPropertySet) propSet.getPropertyValue("Validation");
//          validProp.setPropertyValue("ShowErrorMessage", new Boolean(true));
//          validProp.setPropertyValue("ErrorMessage", "Please enter a valid time");
//          validProp.setPropertyValue("ErrorAlertStyle", ValidationAlertStyle.INFO);       
//
//           propSet.setPropertyValue("Validation", validProp);
//           
             // --- Data validation ---
             com.sun.star.table.XCellRange xCellRange = sheet.getCellRangeByName("A7:C7");
             com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xCellPropSet = (com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet)
                 UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet.class, xCellRange);

             // validation properties
             com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xValidPropSet = (com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet)
                 xCellPropSet.getPropertyValue("Validation");
             xValidPropSet.setPropertyValue("Type", com.sun.star.sheet.ValidationType.DECIMAL);
             xValidPropSet.setPropertyValue("ShowErrorMessage", new Boolean(true));
             xValidPropSet.setPropertyValue("ErrorMessage", "This is an invalid value!");
             xValidPropSet.setPropertyValue("ErrorAlertStyle", com.sun.star.sheet.ValidationAlertStyle.STOP);

             // condition
             com.sun.star.sheet.XSheetCondition xCondition = (com.sun.star.sheet.XSheetCondition)
                 UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.sheet.XSheetCondition.class, xValidPropSet);
             xCondition.setOperator(com.sun.star.sheet.ConditionOperator.BETWEEN);
             xCondition.setFormula1("0.0");
             xCondition.setFormula2("5.0");

             // apply on cell range
             xCellPropSet.setPropertyValue("Validation", xValidPropSet);

      }
```

on the following line:

```
             com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet xValidPropSet = (com.sun.star.beans.XPropertySet)
             xCellPropSet.getPropertyValue("Validation");
```

Comment: The "test class" code is simply a repeat of the other code -- probably a copy/paste error.  Also, we can't tell what line the error occurred on -- which one is 125?

Comment: I apologize; I inadvertently duplicated the helper class instead of providing the actual Test class. The mistake has been corrected. The line throwing the error is `XPropertySet validProp =(XPropertySet) propSet.getPropertyValue("Validation");`

Comment: Completely off-topic, but try to avoid UNO api as much as you can. This is incredibly slow and not very well thought at all, and practically undebuggable... Use something like odf-toolkit or anything working with the document directly in memory. You could save up to 1'000x processing time if your documents are medium to big (source: personnal experience)

Comment: That is very good advice @S. Piller. I did not realize there were even alternatives. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to cast it properly.  The code should be like the example:

```
XPropertySet xCellPropSet = (XPropertySet)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, xCellRange);
```

...instead of this:

```
XPropertySet propSet = UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, range);
```

**EDIT**:

Apparently, the example is incorrect.  Here is working code:

```
XPropertySet validProp = (XPropertySet)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, 
        propSet.getPropertyValue("Validation"));
```

These types of problems are annoying when working with Java and UNO.  I prefer Python and UNO, and one of the reasons is because `queryInterface` is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, adding the cast did not resolve the issue. In hindsight, I realized I should have specified which line was actually throwing the error. I will edit my initial post to include this detail.

Comment: Thank you so much! Wish I could upvote more than once; the answer is definitely worth it. :)